# ampersand converts to &amp; on scroll

Tags: html

This is a very strange. When my `view.cshtml` is rendered it looks great. But when I scroll, the HTML element span translates the ampersand into a **&**. I tried to debug it but there is no further calls to the back-end or script execution when scrolling.

Code :

```
<span data-tooltip="tooltip" data-title="The Conference: Consumer Insight &amp; So Much More" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="The Conference: Consumer Insight &amp; So Much More">The Conference: Consumer Insight &amp;amp; So Much More</span>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you got a link?

Comment: That does sound strange. Can you post the minimum amount of code needed to replicate the issue?

Comment: I posted the code.

Comment: Why do you have `&amp;amp;` in your code?

Comment: That's after scrolling. Before that it is ampersand sign. That's the issue actually.

Comment: @SAFF I have updated your question with a code snipper, please edit it yourself to try to reproduce the issue you are facing.

Comment: I didn't accept your update. That's an irrelevant code.

Comment: How irrelevant? Well then update your question with a code snippet that illustrates the issue because it is not clear and we won't be able to help you otherwise.

Comment: I don't know what to provide. It converts by itself. If you have any idea please answer on this topic. Instead of editing my question without any relevant code.

Comment: Do you have any scripts running on your page? Can you point us to the URL where it's happening?